# What's the purpose of the asrc attribute in Google Plus links?

Tags: html, google-plus

If you inspect one of the buttons at the left side of the page, you see they are made of an `<a>` element similar to this:

```
<a tabindex="-1" 
   alt="Explore" 
   href="/explore" 
   asrc="ribbon" 
   class="g-s-n-aa F9a SX">...</a>
```

Does anybody know what's the purpose of the `asrc` attribute in these anchor tags?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think they serve a functional purpose. Appears to be "microdata" that Google+ embeds to mark the source location of a link, in this case the left nav bar called the "ribbon".